# Angular after update: You need to specify a command before moving on

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

After updating angular to version 14.1.3 every time when I run ng serve I have this error:
You need to specify a command before moving on. Use '--help' to view the available commands.

I have did:
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli

but still same error

Comment: have you tried powershell?

Comment: @NarenMurali yes same issue.

Comment: uninstall node and reinstall then do a fresh install of angular cli